# How to fix "Save Project as template" in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

I want to save my project as template and if I click on

> Tools < Save Project as template

no dialog/popup opening. I need your for help.

Comment: Try to update or maybe re-install Intellij. I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/5nY1WRB.png) when I click on  **Tools > Save Project as template**

Comment: Okay thanks for the help!

Comment: I re-installed and the problem is always there.

Comment: If issue is still not resolved then I'll suggest you to submit a request on [JetBrains IDE support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us#)